# Get Doxygen to show Xcode compile errors if documentation is missing

Tags: xcode, documentation, doxygen, compilation

I have been successful with this in the past but now I can't seem to find the setting that tells Xcode or Doxygen (or both) to display compile errors if documentation is missing.  I have looked at the Apple documentation that tells how to create docsets and that works fine but Xcode does not throw compiling errors on missing comments in the source code.  Anyone know how to get this turned on?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Doxygen generate error when documentation is missing, you have theses options:

- WARNINGS
- WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED
- WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR
- WARN_NO_PARAMDOC

In Xcode, you can launch Doxygen with a `Run Script` build phase. In the "Build Results", every line that begins with "Warning:" will be highlighted in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had WARNINGS, WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED, and WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR checked.  But I did not have the WARN_NO_PARAMDOC.  I have the Run Script already in on my main target.  I made the change and I tried it again.  It still didn't flag missing comments.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you see the output of the doxygen invocation in the build results ? Maybe you don't have the output filter set to "Error and Warnings Only".

Comment: Yes the output of the doxygen was in the build results.  I checked the documentation (HTML) and it is up to date.  The Run Script appears to be working as it should, yet somehow it appears that XCode is not receiving the Warnings/Errors.